# Using sql, find the previous row on base of condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Sql table structure]

I have a table that stores the records for users' different sessions(subscribe, unsubscribe,away, online). I have to calculate the time duration for each session. I can get the previous row using the LAG() function, but LAG() use offset, and I don't know what the offset is. I have to get that previous row `where event NOT IN ('subscribe', 'unsubscribe')`.
Like in the attached image, for row number 8 with event subscribe, the previous row should be row number 4 with event away.
I am using the latest version of MYSQL.

Here is mysql query so far I write, getting results, but I want to get previous row on base of condition, instead of setting a hardcoded offset to 2 in LAG() function.

```
select * from (
  select `id`, `user_id`, `event`, `created_at`,
    date(created_at) as date,
    SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at))) as duration,
    LAG(event,2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at)  AS previous_event,
    CASE
        WHEN event = 'subscribe' and LAG(event,2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) = 'away' THEN 'away'
        WHEN event = 'subscribe' and LAG(event,2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) = 'online' THEN 'online'
        WHEN event = 'subscribe' and LAG(event,2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) IS NULL THEN 'online'
        ELSE event END as status
    from `user_websocket_events` where event in ('online','away','unsubscribe','subscribe') and created_at between '2022-04-06 00:00:00' and '2022-04-07 23:59:59' and user_id in(19)
  ) as `Developer`
where created_at between '2022-04-06 00:00:00' and '2022-04-06 23:59:59';

#data for testing
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9606, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9609, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9610, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9611, 19, 'away');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9613, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9614, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9616, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9618, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9634, 19, 'online');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9635, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9636, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9637, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9638, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9639, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9640, 19, 'subscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9641, 19, 'away');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9642, 19, 'unsubscribe');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event) VALUES (9643, 19, 'subscribe');
```

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: *for row number 8 with event subscribe, the previous row should be row number 4 with event away.* ?? for rows 6,11,13,15 the "previous row" is row 4 too?

Comment: for 6 and 8 previous row is 4. but for 11,13,15 the previous row is 9(because the event is not equal to subscribe and unsubscribe) and then for 18 the previous row should be 16.

Comment: @Akina thanks for letting me know about the proper way to ask the question on the platform.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the answer. I am adding this to my query. Can you please help me with where should I learn some advanced SQL? Or it will come with the passage of time and experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the next query:

```sql
SELECT *,
       SUM(event NOT IN ('subscribe', 'unsubscribe')) OVER (ORDER BY id) group_no
FROM user_websocket_events
ORDER BY 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d313c095f5c034a0a03cf70defd8344a

This query divides the rowset to groups, each group starts from an event which is not 'subscribe' or 'unsubscribe'.

So for any row you can easily find the `id` value for *previous row where `event NOT IN ('subscribe', 'unsubscribe')`* with simple `MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY group_no)`. Of course for non-zero group number.

Comment: thanks for the query. I am adding this to my query. Can you please help me with where should I learn some advanced SQL? Or it will come with the passage of time and experience.

Comment: @link2developer Practice, practice and practice again. For example, there - open any question where the task seems to be simple enough but some subtleties are present. Try to solve, the best way try to create 2-3 solutions. Then look at the answers. If there is an answer with the solution which differs from your ones - analyze it, try to understand what trick was used.

Comment: Can you please mention, where I have to put this query inside my query and how I can use that id of the previous row to get a row, all this in a single query? You can see my query above in the question, you can remove the LAG section.

Comment: Got it. I appreciated your advice.

Comment: @link2developer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9874860c2c752c0c100dd18acfe768e2

Comment: awesome, you are an angel for me. Lifesaver. Thanksssssssssssssss.

Comment: just last question, what is order by 1,4. I didn't get that 4.

Comment: @link2developer Numbers in GROUP BY and ORDER BY means "n-th output column". Rremove this ORDER BY simply or add one you need in.